# Why does this basic Java boolean expression not work?

Tags: java

Why does this not compute in Java (v1.8). Seems perfectly logical to me....

```
boolean banana = true;
(banana == true || false) ? System.out.println("True") : System.out.println("False");
```

**Output message:** Error: java: not a statement

Comment: you need `String res =  (banana == true || false) ? "True" : "False";` , `System.out.println()` returns void, or more appropriately `System.out.println(banana ? "True" : "False");`

Comment: I wonder what sense this `|| false` should make ...

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: The OP obviously attempted what is cited above. Personally I don't see a problem with the quality of the question. Obviousness ought not to equate to downvotes. And it *would* be logical if `println` was an *expression*. `|| false` is a no-op; that's all.

Comment: Reopened. This question is also about the expression `(banana == true || false)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The ternary conditional operator must return a value. The second and third operands can't be statements that don't return anything. They must be expressions that return a value.

You could switch it to :

```
System.out.println(banana ? "True" : "False");
```

Note that `banana == true || false` is equivalent to `banana == true`, which is equivalent to `banana` as `banana` itself is a `boolean` type.

Comment: Added a final bit: please remove if you don't like it. (In C and C++ it would also be equivalent if `banana` were an integral type.)

Comment: @Bathsheba That's a useful addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
System.out.println(banana ? "true" : "false");
```

The ternary operator always has to return a value which we're printing.

---

The other way is only using `if-else` statement, but it's not pretty.

```
if(banana)
    System.out.println("true");
else
    System.out.println("false");
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Java Language Specification §15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) says:

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand
>   expression to be an invocation of a void method.

Better try like this:

```
System.out.println(banana ? "true" : "false");
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
boolean banana = true;
System.out.println(banana ? "True" : "False");
```

A `? :` operator has to return a value and println is a `void` method. Not only does it do what you want, it is more concise.

Note

```
banana == true
```

is the same as

```
banana
```

and

```
x || false
```

is the same as

```
x
```

Also unless you need to print "True" instead of "true" you can do

```
System.out.println(banana);
```

Comment: isn't `banana || false` unnecessary could be just `(banana ? "True" : "False"`

Answer (score 1):

You are using it incorrectly.

One use of the Java ternary operator (also called the conditional operator) is to assign the minimum (or maximum) value of two variables to a third variable, essentially replacing a Math.min(a,b) or Math.max(a,b) method call. Here's an example that assigns the minimum of two variables, a and b, to a third variable named minVal is:

```
minVal = (a < b) ? a : b;
```

You can do it like this.

```
if(boolean)
   System.out.println("True");
else  
   System.out.println("False");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess because Java won't allow statement like that.

Try using `if` statement.

```
boolean banana = true;
if (banana == true || false) System.out.println("True"); else System.out.println("False");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there are only false bananas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_banana. There is not any one "true" banana. You are likely thinking of the "true plantain", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_plantains. Changing your banana to false will allow your code to once again be copacetic with biology.